# hide common package in doxygen output

Tags: java, doxygen

Given some packages `foo.bar.project.something.FirstModule`  `foo.bar.project.something.SecondModule`, etc. They all have that long `foo.bar.project.something` in common. How do I tell doxygen to hide (or at least shorten) those common package names and only print `FirstModule.SomeClass` and `SecondModule.MyInterface` in its output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could set HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES to YES, but that will probably also strip FirstModule and SecondModule.

An alternative is to write a simple input filter (see INPUT_FILTER in the doxygen config file) that replaces "package foo.bar.project.something.AModule;" by "package AModule;". Then you have full control over how much is stripped.

Comment: Yes, that worked! Great, thanks. For the record: `INPUT_FILTER = "sed 's/package my.beloved.packages.\(.*\);/package \1;/'"`