# Doxygen : how to strip eu.mycompany from the package names

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I've already look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677951/hide-common-package-in-doxygen-output) but I still don't understand how to just keep a certain part of the package hierachy to display the class names (working under Windows)?

Comment: Rather than using `sed` try one of the solutions to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/127318/623518

Comment: Thanks, so I dowloaded UnixUtils, add UnixUtils/usr/local/wbin to my path and in the Doxygen Wizard I wrote the followinf for INPUT_FILTER:sed "s/package eu.mycompany.myproject.\(.*\);/package \1;/". It woks!

Comment: Great to hear. Perhaps you should add and accept that as an answer, if it has answered your question.

Comment: It has answered but how can I mak a comment as a correct answer?

Comment: You can't. Write you comment as an answer (below), expanding on the comment if necessary, and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris tip of using UnixUtils works well for me